# how I plot the output of table function in r

Tags: r, plot

I used the function **table(d$x)**. How I can plot the output of table function? No restriction on the plot type it could be anything: bar, pie chart or histogram.

Comment: It's good practice to include a reproducible example, visualization decisions can be influenced by nature of the data and the relative proportions.

Comment: have you tried `plot(table(d$x))`? What's wrong with that? You might also try `barplot(table(d$x))`.

Comment: Or maybe `as.data.frame(table(d$x))`. We need a reproducible example to see what's exactly happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function can be used :
plot(table_name)